# How to prove this $2$ norm inequality of the Schur complement?

Tags: linear-algebra, block-matrices

We have $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ which is symmetric and positive-definite. Also, $A$ is a block matrix:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

Let,  $S = A_{22} - A_{21}A_{11}^{-1}A_{12}$  be the Schur complement. How can one demonstrate that,

$$||S||_{2} \le ||A||_{2}?$$
I looked at the block Cholesky factorization given in this document but it is no help. Thanks!

[https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~bindel/class/cs4220-s16/lec/2016-02-17-notes.pdf](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/%7Ebindel/class/cs4220-s16/lec/2016-02-17-notes.pdf)

Comment: $\|S\|_2\le\|A_{22}\|_2\le\|A\|_2$.

Comment: @user1151,

How does one show that $$||S||_{2} \le ||A_{22}||_{2}? $$

Does it follow from the Cholesky decomposition in the documents? Thank you!

Comment: It's because $0\prec S\prec A_{22}$.

Comment: @user1551, can you please expand on how that inequality implies
$$ ||S||_{2} \le ||A_{22}||_{2}?$$
I know from the Cauchy Schwarz inequality we can obtain:


$$x^{*}Sx \le x^{*}A_{22}x \implies x^{*}Sx \le ||A_{22}||_{2}.$$

Comment: @TobiasRieper Since $S$ and $A_{22}$ are positive definite, their induced $2$-norms are their largest eigenvalues. By Rayleigh's variational characterisation, the largest eigenvalue of any Hermitian matrix $H$ is equal to $\max_{\|x\|_2=1}x^\ast Hx$. As $S\prec A_{22}$, we have $\max_{\|x\|_2=1}x^\ast Sx\le\max_{\|x\|_2=1}x^\ast A_{22}x$.

Comment: @user1551, hey sorry to bother again but how did you obtain the inequality that:
$$ 0\prec S\prec A_{22} ?$$

Thank you so much!

Comment: @Johndoe Since $A$ is positive definite and it is congruent to $A_{11}\oplus S$ (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) for instance), $S$ must be positive definite. Furthermore, $S-A_{22}=-A_{21}A_{11}^{-1}A_{12}$ is negative definite. Hence $S\prec A_{22}$.